# Data transfer between Java Swing forms

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 5 forms, one of which opens when the other is closed. 2nd member login screen. The last one is the ticket purchase screen. Reservations are made on the ticket purchasing screen. Member information is kept in the database. If the e-mail and password on the login screen match, login with those in the database. I want to access the current user in the last form.

Unfortunately, I did not take action for this from the beginning. Now, if the login is successful, I can take the user's e-mail and forward it to the last form. I can access the member id from this email and add the member information in the final reservation process.

I cannot forward your member email to the last form! That's the problem. I've done a lot of switching between forms, but I can only do this with forms that are opened and closed consecutively. If I create an object with the constructor and type `setVisible(true)` in the following way, the email is transferred, but the last form opens after the 1st form. If I remove the `setVisible` method or make false, even if the data is transferred at the last part, I cannot use it because I cannot print it on the label.

```
 private void btnMemberEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        BiletAl pencere2 = new BiletAl(txtUyeEPosta.getText(),lbl.getText());
        pencere2.setVisible(true);}
```

- 

```
public class BiletAl extends javax.swing.JFrame { 


public BiletAl() {
    initComponents();
    
   
}

public BiletAl(String gelenEPosta,String lbl) {
    initComponents();
    System.out.println(gelenEPosta);
    lblGelenEposta.setVisible(true);
    lblGelenEposta.setText(gelenEPosta);
    
   
}
```

If this happens: the form opening order is broken. but "nil" text, i.e. the entered e-mail is transferred to the label:

[image]
[image]

```
private void btnMemberEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        BiletAl pencere2 = new BiletAl(txtUyeEPosta.getText(),lbl.getText());
       }
```

If the first part changes just like this:Switching between forms is correct, but even if the data coming as constructor parameter with `System.out.println` is correct, it does not add it to the label when `setLabel`. The label does not write "nil" in the incoming email.

[image]

Comment: *"I have 5 forms.."* If by 'forms' you mean `JFrame` instances (and please use the class names) then this has already gone wrong. These 5 views should be packed into a `CardLayout` &/or dialogs other than a single `JFrame` for the main app.

Comment: A multi-JPanel application requires a data model to keep everything together.  A data model consists of one or more plain Java classes to hold all of the reservation information.  A data model communicates with the database.  A data model populates the view, which consists of one JFrame and multiple JPanels.  The controller classes are the ActionListener classes that respond to JButton clicks.  The [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern helps maintain a separation of concerns and makes the application easier to understand.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've never heard of the concept of CardLayout and / or dialog boxes. I'm at a more basic level. That's why I was able to do the transitions using the setVisible () function. I am even aware that this does not provide a complete transition. Yes, what I call forms are jFrames. Excuse me I thought they were the same as form.

Comment: *"I'm at a more basic level."* It's going to take a more advanced level of understanding of Swing to get it working with `JFrame` than it would to learn how to do it using layouts and dialogs. Further, if you try it that way, people are a lot more likely to help. *"I've never heard of the concept of CardLayout and / or dialog boxes."* That's why I brought them to your attention. Anybody who was familiar with them would know it was the best approach. So the time to familiarize yourself with them *is **now***.

Comment: @AndrewThompson While trying to learn and understand Java in a basic sense, we were given such a serious project assignment. I'm trying to do cinema automation. Swing, I never knew the database. Because of the time, I had to learn as much as I could use it quickly. I can not only make the reservation part. A wrong way of learning you are right. It would be great for me in this stressful situation if you can share easy-to-understand resources on the parts you say please. Thank you.

Comment: *"easy-to-understand resources"* Put 'X Java tutorial' in a search engine, where X is the class in question, e.g. `CardLayout` or `JDialog`. The top hit should be to the Java Tutorial which comes right from the horses mouth and typically include example code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Of course, straight google search is right. Of course I did, as soon as I hear what these are. I still asked to mean I can get suggestions. Unfortunately, I have 7 days for my project right now. I will definitely research and learn what you said, but it will take a lot of time to write a project with them again. So, what kind of solution can be thought of to my question, even if it is a wrong way? Do you have an idea?

Comment: *"So, what kind of solution can be thought of to my question, even if it is a wrong way?"* I'm not wasting my time thinking about it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well you are right :( Thank you.

Comment: It won't take a lot of time to use `JPanel`s instead of `JFrame`s... literally all your layouts are done, in fact you will find it much faster even if you don't use the MVC pattern and simply expose methods in your various `JPanel`s that help to pass information around, or use the constructors or a singleton pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Then try to use this commands:

1)this.setVisible(true);
2)this.setVisible(false);